# Prehilbertspace = Inner Product Space = Unitary Vector Space?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Are pre-hilbert space, inner product space, unitary (in the complex case) or euclidian (in the real case) vector space the same things, just synonyms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the same because all of them refer to a vector space (finite or infinite dimensional) with an inner product. The only detail I could think of is that you may have a complete inner product space or unitary space which in fact would be a Hilbert space (not just a pre-Hilbert).